# How to make class to allow creation of 3 objects only

Tags: c#, java, oop

i was asked this question in my interview that how to make a class that can only allows 3 objects creation.

i suggested to take a static variable and a static function for creation of object and while returning reference of new object just check value in static variable to check count of no. of object already created.

second approach i told him to take 3 static object of same class in that class only and let the user use those object only.

please tell me the best approach to perform above operation.

Thanks

Comment: where you have been interviewd ? EXFO

Comment: I would not want to work for a company that thinks this is a good interview question in any way. I would run away screaming, really.

Comment: @Karl - An interview question is not necessarily indicative of programming practices. I think your comment is a massive overreaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your first approach is closer to the question: make private constructor and a static `newInstance()` method that checks how many instances were created before and returns null if it's more than 3.

Second approach is also ok, though.

**EDIT** @Saurabh: even though the question says nothing about what to do in case the object is gc-ed, let's develop this:

1. A dirty hack to the first solution: override `finalize()` method that decrements the static counter of objects.
2. A pool of objects with some sort of a locking mechanism that only allows three, let's say, users, use the objects ate the same time.

Comment: What about if one of the object garbage collected

Comment: Does it matter if any of the objects were GCed? The question is how to only all 3 to be created, not ensure that only 3 exist at any point in time.

Comment: @Saurabh - Seems very unlikely so long as there is a static reference to them.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, the simplest solution would be to use an enum.

Answer (score 2):

Step one would be to write your own VM. Reflection could be used to circumvent most of the answers here, a customised classloader would defeat them all. Moral of the story: sufficiently privileged code can do whatever it wants to your classes.

Comment: +1 : for Reflection bit , i were aware of what you are talking about , simpley whole Singleton Pattern can be broken with reflection and i know that but sometime you just need to answer what is asked.

Answer (score 1):

my implementation is would be as below , it is not perfect but my thoughts at initial

```
 public class ThreeInstances
{

    private static int TOTALINSTANCECOUNT = 0;

    private ThreeInstances()
    {
    }

     private object objLock = new object();

     private static List<ThreeInstances> objThreeInstances = new List<ThreeInstances>();

     public static ThreeInstances GetInstance()
     {

         if (TOTALINSTANCECOUNT < 3)
         {
             lock (objLock)
             {
                 objThreeInstances.Add(new ThreeInstances());
                 Interlocked.Increment(ref TOTALINSTANCECOUNT);
                 return objThreeInstances[TOTALINSTANCECOUNT];

             }

         }
         else
         {
             Random r = new Random(0);
          int value =    r.Next(2);
          return objThreeInstances[value];
         }


     }

     ~ThreeInstances()
     {
         Interlocked.Decrement(ref TOTALINSTANCECOUNT);

         if (TOTALINSTANCECOUNT < 3)
         {
             lock (objLock)
             {
                 objThreeInstances.Add(new ThreeInstances());
                 Interlocked.Increment(ref TOTALINSTANCECOUNT);
                 return objThreeInstances[TOTALINSTANCECOUNT];

             }

         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Singleton design pattern** with some modifications two support three instances instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this... simple Singleton Pattern... You can add direct access for the three instances via Getters.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class ThreeInstanceClazz {

    private static ArrayList<ThreeInstanceClazz> instances= null;

    private ThreeInstanceClazz(){
        // Only a private constructor!!
    }

    public static ThreeInstanceClazz getInstance(){
        if(instances == null){
            instances = new ArrayList<ThreeInstanceClazz>(3);
        }

        if(instances.size() < 3){
            ThreeInstanceClazz newOne = new ThreeInstanceClazz();
            instances.add(new ThreeInstanceClazz());

            // return newly created
            return newOne;
        }else{
            // return random instance ... or anything else
            Collections.shuffle(instances);
            return instances.get(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out Noldorin's answer in [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251445/limit-instances-creation-of-a-class) thread. May this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Threeobject
{
    public static int objectcount { get; set; }

    public Threeobject()
    {
        if (Threeobject.objectcount >= 3)
        {
            throw new Exception("You cannot create more then three object");
        }
        Threeobject.objectcount++;
    }
}
```