# Singleton-like pattern allowing to create more than one instance in C#

Tags: c#, .net, singleton

Is there a realisation of a Singleton-like pattern which allows to create more than one instance (e.g 5 instances and no more). I guess it will be called *Multiton Pattern*.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Technically this is possible; not sure how common it actually is in practice.

Comment: So... something like a [threadpool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx)?

Comment: i sense a little contradiction where you want to create multiple objects and you want it to be thread safe? what s the purpose if you dont allow each thread to get their instances and you dont want singleton?

Comment: Might be a better question if you ask from the use-case.

Comment: Guys, for me it's just a interesting question. I can try to make some solution, but I want to hear experts that is your voice!

Comment: I found an article in Wikipedia, it seems there is a formal pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern

Comment: @Arterius Per the article, that pattern isn't quite the same as you asked for: it's described as a "keyed Singleton", ensuring one instance *per key*. It doesn't necessarily enforce a maximum number of instances. That would be closer to a pooling pattern, as others have mentioned.

Comment: @djacobson Ok, I agreed :) It's now clear for me. Thank you all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to perform some kind of object pooling?

If so, here's a solution I found with a quick Google search. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/DotNetObjectPool.aspx

If I'm wrong, and you have a legit reason for limiting the number of instances, here's another SO question addressing this very pattern: [Limit instances creation of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251445/limit-instances-creation-of-a-class)

Comment: Thank you! It just a question from my last interview.

Comment: It's possible, but I can't really conceive of a reason why you'd limit the number, without the purpose to pooling instances for reuse.

Answer (score 3):

The pattern is called an [Object Pool Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/object-pool-pattern.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such functionality out of the box. However, you can use [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) to synchronize the maximum count of resources, which are acquired and freed.

From the other hand you can use a usual [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx) to synchronize access to some variable, which will hold the currently created number of instances.